# Classification on Imbalanced Class

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-modeling, modeling, data-analysis

Been trying to classify a dataset where there is clear class imbalance problem. For a definitive dataset of 1500, there are 108 1's, and rest are 0's- 1 & 0 indicate definite classes. 
Using Decision Tree to create a model. Used methods to correct class imbalance problem such as ADABoost, SMOTE etc. but the problem is- 
- It predicts well when I use it to predict for Test sets
BUT
when I take a random dataset of 0.1 Million, its prediction is unbelievably skewed- such as 80% for 0's and 20% for 1- which can't be true.

What am I missing out?

Comment: This kinda implies that the outliers of 1's dominate the decision boundary to this degree. I would advise you to train on a balanced dataset, e.g. throw out additional 1's at training time to get a balanced result.

Comment: You mean additional 0's.. Did that. No change in results.

Comment: I mean using a balanced dataset for training. It might only be 1/10 of the size of the original dataset, but this might still be better than what you have now. Contrary to popular belief more data is not always better.

Comment: I think that technics like ADABoost gives importance(weight > 1) to difficult instance(in your case class 1). that implies your new dataset will not have the same ratio of class 1 comparing to the first dataset. my intuition is if you use technics to balance your dataset. you need to correct  (calibrate) your probabilities predictions (if you are using a probalistic model). this articl explain how to use logistic regression for rare events (http://gking.harvard.edu/files/0s.pdf)